# What does "Foner's it in" mean?

Tags: meaning

If is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/6bMq9Ek6jnA). It is at 14 minute and 12 second.

> We will give our last words today to Eric Foner, who never **Foner's it in**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pun on the cliché of "phoning it in."

To "phone [something] in" (as a job or a task) means to do the absolute minimum required. It suggests a lack of care, discipline, or interest, and it is one of the most damning statements someone can make about an employee or other person who is supposed to be responsible for said task. Figuratively, it means they didn't even show up in person.

The pun is rather labored: *Foner's it in **=>** phones it in*. But it means Foner is no slouch when it comes to doing a job right.

Comment: And, might I add, a really *bad* pun at that.  :P